# Script to Change Row Color with a input from a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Basic conditioning formatting issue, (or so I thought); our spreadsheet acts as a Daily log, therefore, besides the top row (frozen titles), everything gets manually moved to an archive on a daily basis. This renders the innate Conditional Formatting function inert as it not longer works after the data move.

So I found an modified a script until it works exactly the way we need it to, with one minor issue, all input is gathered thru the use of a Google Form, and even though the script works when the value in question is manually entered it does not function when entered thru the form, I tried using a trigger but to no avail.

When the form is filled and submitted, a Radio Button (if selected), enters ME? onto column E, if that value is entered then A2:E gets a change in the font color and cell background color, otherwise is business as usual. This is the script as it currently stands:

```
function OnEdit(e) {
if (e) { 
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 
    if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Form Responses 0") {

        ME = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 5).getValue();
        rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,5);

        // This changes font and row color
        if (ME == 'ME?') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#056afa");
            rowRange.setBackground("#fae7bf");

        // DEFAULT
        } else if (ME == ' ') { 
            rowRange.setFontColor("#000000");
            rowRange.setBackground("#ffffff");
        }   
    }
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) only works for user edits.  Why not just use [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)?

Answer (score 0):

Since this trigger must be activated from an event, not from a user action, you shall create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) using the [`On form submit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) type. First, I strongly recommend changing your function name from `OnEdit(e)` (that looks very similar to the reserved trigger [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)) to some descriptive name (I used `colorUpdater(e)`). You can add the installable trigger from the App Script editor, using the menu `Edit  Current project's triggers`. There you must click `+ Add Trigger` and select the following parameters:

- Choose which function to run: colorUpdater
- Choose which deployment should run: Head
- Select event source: From spreadsheet
- Select event type: On form submit
- Failure notification settings: as you wish

You can find more information about this process on the [managing triggers manually documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Then you will need to update your function to look like the following code. It is your original function with some little changes that I made to implement the new approach.

```
function colourUpdater(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Form Responses 0") {
    var rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 5, 1, 1);
    var ME = rowRange.getValue();
    if (ME == 'ME?') {
      // This changes font and row color
      rowRange.setFontColor("#056afa");
      rowRange.setBackground("#fae7bf");
    } else {
      // DEFAULT
      rowRange.setFontColor("#000000");
      rowRange.setBackground("#ffffff");
    }
  }
}
```

Please, ask me for clarification if you need more information or this approach doesn't fulfills your original request.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Jacques, but more inportant, thank you for the time you took to explain in greater detail the reason behind my issue,

Comment: Hi there @Getsemani! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.